# PyMongo and MongoDB $each modifier

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I seem to be having trouble with the $each modifier in PyMongo/MongoDB. Assume I have an array called `tags`.

I can update the database like this and it works:

```
   for tag in tags:
      db_collection.update({'username':username},{'$push':{'docs.tags': tag }})
```

However, instead of performing multiple writes to the database, I thought it would be more efficient to use the `$each` modifier. In theory, this could be written without a loop as:

```
db_collection.update({'username':username},{'$push':{'docs.tags': {'$each': tags} }})
```

But it does not work. It seems that PyMongo does not detect the $each modifier or something else. It still stores, but the result is a dictionary like this:

```
{'$each': [tag1, tag2, ...] }
```

Is there an issue with the way I am writing it or is this actually nothing to worry about. As in, is there no performance impact if I do it the first way.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my version of mongoDB did not support the $each modifier for $push. $addToSet works but I will end up upgrading my mongoDB.